# Why when I try to use react native hooks it does not work properly as intended to be?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks, device-orientation

I am developing an app using react native, when I try to `console.log(useDeviceOrientation());`. The output (**true/false**) during the portrait and landscape did not change. Could someone help?

The library that is used is: @react-native-community/hooks

API that I used: useDeviceOrientation

What I try to do:

1. uninstall the library
2. reinstall the same library
3. add dependencies of the library to package.json
4. same problem occurred. no changes when changing orientation

Code:

```
// import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React from 'react';
import { Dimensions, StyleSheet, SafeAreaView, Alert, Button, Platform, StatusBar, View } from 'react-native';
import { useDimensions, useDeviceOrientation } from '@react-native-community/hooks'

export default function App() {
  console.log(useDeviceOrientation());
  const { landscape } = useDeviceOrientation();

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <View style={{
        backgroundColor: "dodgerblue",
        width: "100%",
        height: landscape ? "100%" : "30%",
      }}
      ></View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    paddingTop: Platform.OS === "android" ? StatusBar.currentHeight : 0,
    // justifyContent: "center",
    // alignItems: "center",
  },
});
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: You need to give more details. You haven't mentioned the lib you are using, what you have already tried...

Answer (score 3):

There is no need for 3rd party library for this. You can use this approach.
First, create a functional component named useOrientarion,

```
import { useWindowDimensions } from 'react-native';

const useOrientation = () => {
  const { width, height } = useWindowDimensions();

  return { isPortrait: height > width };
};

export default useOrientation;
```

and then in your component,

```
// import useOrientation
import useOrientation from './useOrientation';

function App() {
  const orientation = useOrientation();
  console.log(orientation);
  // use orientation wherever you want
  // OUTPUT:  {"isPortrait": true} or  {"isPortrait": false}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

it works for me.

```
const { height, width } = useDimensions().window;
const landscape = width > height;
```

[react-native-community](https://github.com/react-native-community/hooks/issues/202#issuecomment-724706582)

Comment: I think OP is saying the useDeviceOrientation hook specifically doesn't work cause I'm running into the same problem with it's value not updating when the orientation changes. This code is super helpful though, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is a known issue that they are working on: https://github.com/react-native-community/hooks/issues/210. @ReadRise answer works great as a workaround it though!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue; stopping the app and re-building was sufficient to have it fixed.